# Difficulty in reading this old paper on coding theory

Tags: coding-theory, reed-muller-codes

I am reading an old report on the weight distribution of BCH codes, written by Tadao Kasami. The link to the report can be found here https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/items/100343/bitstreams/320511/stream

I am also attaching the images of the paper where I have difficulty understanding the content.

Now, if you can see the attached image, you will find two pages. Go to the first page, and look for the mathematical equation I have highlighted with yellow color.
You will find this equation $h_i(\alpha^{- 2^{\mu_i}- 1}) = 0$. But, my reasoning says that the aforementioned equation should look this $h_i(\alpha^{ (-2)^{\mu_i}- 1}) = 0$. What do you say, guys? Please share your thought.

Now, go to the second page, and look for the highlighted equation. You will find this equation $[m/2] - [m/3] + 2 \geq p $. It doesn't make any sense to put square brackets around $m/2$ and $m/3$. So, according to me, this equation should look like eighter this $\lfloor m/2 \rfloor - \lfloor m/3 \rfloor + 2 \geq p$, or this $ \lceil m/2 \rceil - \lceil m/3 \rceil + 2 \geq p $, Which one of them, according to you guys? Please share your thoughts.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The second question is easily answered. The Kasami report was typed on an [IBM Selectric](https://www.ibm.com/ibm/history/ibm100/us/en/icons/selectric/) typewriter which had a golfball head for ordinary letters and correspondence.  The golfball head was exchangeable with a different golfball head for scientific notation (Greek alphabet, some symbols including $[$ and $]$ but *not* $\lfloor$ or $\rfloor$ or $\lceil$ or $\rceil$) and so Kasami had to make do with $[\cdot]$ instead of the more modern $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ that younger folks freely use. (Typing mathematics was particularly time-consuming because the heads had to be swapped in and out constantly).  I *know*; I joined the Coordinated Science Laboratory of the University of Illinois in 1973 (about 5 years after Kasami returned to Japan) and IBM Selectrics were still in use for a decade or so until laser-printers become ubiquitous and small enough to fit on a desktop.

A more readable version of Kasami's results (and extensions thereof) can be found in Chapter 16 of Berlekamp's 1968 textbook *Algebraic Coding Theory* (McGraw-Hill but reprinted by other publishers since then).

Comment: Darn kids today, spoiled with $\LaTeX$, don't understand the struggles of typesetting math with a typewritter or locally enhanced troff... ;)

Comment: @Dilip ; Can you answer my first question?

Comment: @Dilip ; I also need to cite this report. But as you can see this report hasn't been published anywhere. Any idea how can I cite this report?

Comment: @RobinKurtz Most people cite it as a report and leave it at that.  CSL has no printed copies left (I snagged one of the last ones) but, as you found, the report can be found online from illinois.edu.  In. many cases, including the URL with the exact report citation is adequate. Most of the report can also found in an obscure  1967 conference proceedings (_Combinatorial Mathematics and Its Applications,_ Univ. North Carolina Press; I have never seen an actual paper copy) which is probably not online either.

Comment: @DilipSarwate ; I read Chapter 16 of the book Algebraic Coding Theory. That book doesn't talk about the weight distribution of the kind of BCH codes which Kasami has given in his report. Am I missing something?